# DispatchQueue.main.sync swift

Tags: ios, swift, json.net, synchronization

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    DispatchQueue.global().async(execute: {
        print("teste")
            print("main thread")
            self.getWeather(city: "Minsk")
        print("Hello")
        
    })
    print("working")
}

func getWeather(city: String) {
    
    let cityEscaped = city.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlHostAllowed)
    
    let path = "http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Minsk&appid=..." // appid removed for the sake of privacy
    let url = URL(string: path)
    let session = URLSession.shared
    
    let task = session.dataTask(with: url!) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in
        let json = JSON(data!)
        let lon = json["coord"]["lon"].double
        let lat = json["coord"]["lat"].double
        let temp = json["main"]["temp"].double
        let name = json["name"].string
        let desc = json["weather"][0]["description"].string
        
        print("Lat: \(lat!) lon:\(lon!) temp: \(temp!) city: \(name!)")
    }
    
    task.resume()
}
```

What can I do in order to print a string "Lat: (lat!) lon:(lon!) temp: (temp!) city: (name!)" and after that the execution will be continued?

Comment: translate your question...

Comment: do you want to first print result then download it?

Comment: Чтобы "Hello" вывелось после "lat lon" имеете в виду?

Comment: You should ask here your question in English. Or you can ask your question https://ru.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do something after `getWeather` is done, add a completion handler. Personally, I'd simplify this by creating a structure to pass back the captured information:

```
struct WeatherReport {
    let latitude: Double
    let longitude: Double
    let temperature: Double
    let name: String
    let desc: String
}

func getWeather(city: String, completion: @escaping (WeatherReport?, Error?) -> Void) {

    ...

    let task = session.dataTask(with: url!) { data, _, error in
        ...
        guard successful else {
            completion(nil, error)
            return
        }

        let weatherReport = WeatherReport(...)
        completion(weatherReport, nil) 
    }

    task.resume()
}
```

Then

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    getWeather(city: "Minsk") { weatherReport, error in
        guard let weatherReport = weatherReport, error == nil else {
            print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")
            return
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            // do something with `weatherReport` here
        }
    }
}
```

Note, `dataTask` already (a) runs asynchronously; and (b) runs its completion handler on a background thread, so `viewDidLoad` has to explicitly dispatch anything it does with model objects and/or the UI to the main queue in the `getWeather` completion handler, like shown above.

---

By the way, if you're using Swift 4, I'd suggest eliminate that third party JSON parsing library and use `JSONDecoder` and a model structure that is `Decodable`, e.g.:

```
struct Coordinate: Decodable {
    let latitude: Double
    let longitude: Double

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case latitude = "lat"
        case longitude = "lon"
    }
}

struct WeatherReportDetails: Decodable {
    let temperature: Double
    let pressure: Double
    let humidity: Double
    let temperatureMin: Double
    let temperatureMax: Double

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case pressure, humidity
        case temperature = "temp"
        case temperatureMin = "temp_min"
        case temperatureMax = "temp_max"
    }
}

struct WeatherReport: Decodable {
    let coordinate: Coordinate
    let details: WeatherReportDetails
    let name: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name
        case coordinate = "coord"
        case details = "main"
    }
}
```

And then

```
func getWeather(city: String, completion: @escaping (WeatherReport?, Error?) -> Void) {
    let cityEscaped = city.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlHostAllowed)!
    let urlString = "http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + cityEscaped + "&appid=..." // appid removed for privacy’s sake
    let url = URL(string: urlString)!

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, _, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            completion(nil, error)
            return
        }

        do {
            let weatherReport = try JSONDecoder().decode(WeatherReport.self, from: data)
            completion(weatherReport, nil)
        } catch {
            completion(nil, error)
        }
    }

    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: @HeltyrCafry - By the way, I don't know if you're using Swift 3 or Swift 4, but if Swift for you might want to retire the third party JSON library and use Swift 4's new `JSONDecoder` API and the `Decodable` protocol. See revised answer. (If using Swift 3, feel free to ignore. Lol.)